# What are the different image size formats available via Instagram API

Tags: instagram

I noticed that in the Instagram API  when you get an image back, it looks something like this:

```
http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/a0efb5b418b711e391bd22000a1fbf1d_7.jpg
```

And by changing the `_7` to say `_5` or `_6` you can get different sizes. But I have also noticed that some of the other sizes are NOT always available. Does anyone have info on what sizes are available or can you point me to a resource in the Instagram API that goes into more detail on image sizes supported via the API? Thanks.

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016142/instagram-api-custom-image-width/21394369#21394369

Comment: Is there anyway to get this directly via the API?

Comment: I think there are 3 sizes supported in the API see: https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram/issues/7

Comment: Did you even get an answers for this? This is something that I have been looking into too and from the API it seems that it will only provide 640px, 320px and 150px.

Answer (score 10):

The [Instagram API](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) should always return images in three sizes. All of which are square with side length of **150px**, **306px** and **612px**. Videos are available at 480px square and 640px square resolutions.

```
"images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
```

Comment: See my subsequent notes on this question, which mentions a new undocumented image size at 1080px x 1080px http://stackoverflow.com/a/32070650/385619