# How to optimize the size of instagram images in a stream

Tags: api, instagram

I want to optimize the size of the images sent by the Instagram feed of a module on my prestashop shop.

How can I request images in smaller sizes, like 134x134px or 150x150px ...

My origin picture is : 
https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/2c273bea214e232de2a2d6ded00cfd57/5D306C5B/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c135.0.809.809/s640x640/52890210_803725976651019_6529311483719815543_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com

But i will just, this picture is resized in HTML or CSS from 640x640 to 135x135.

Serving a scaled image could save 91.4KiB (95% reduction).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the different image size formats available via Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394100/what-are-the-different-image-size-formats-available-via-instagram-api)

Answer (score 0):

The **[imagecopyresampled()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)** PHP function is perfect for this task, here is an example:

```
<?php

$filename = './test-instagram-orig.jpg';
$dest_filename = './test-instagram-resized.jpg';
$new_width = 150;
$new_height = 150;
$my_instagram_image = file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents('https://scontent-sjc3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/9844eb2fd4f4012141feef47d2eb97b2/5D389B06/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/10249289_1618492008409419_392402572_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-sjc3-1.cdninstagram.com'));

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($image_p, $dest_filename, 100);
imagedestroy($image_p);

echo '<img src="'.$filename.'" alt="" /> <img src="'.$dest_filename.'" alt="" />';
```

Voila! Of course you should integrate the following code into your module and make the appropriate changes.