# Instagram Video Sizes

Tags: video, instagram

Are multiple video sizes supported in the Instagram API. I know that it is possible to get different [photo sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016142/instagram-api-custom-image-width/21394369#21394369) from the [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#), is the same possible with video (by manipulating the video URL)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 video sizes available in API, 480x480 and 640x640

```
"videos":{
   "low_resolution": {
       "url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/4037059e6fb311e3a03d123d3cfc7775_102.mp4",
       "width":480,
       "height":480
   },
   "standard_resolution":{
       "url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com\/4037059e6fb311e3a03d123d3cfc7775_101.mp4",
       "width":640,
       "height":640
   }
}
```

640x640 video:

`distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxx_101.mp4`, **_101** at the end of file name

480x480 video:

`distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxx_102.mp4`, **_102** at the end of file name